# Bad state: StreamSink is closed

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart and tried write some test web server.
Don't see any problem here, just looked into docs and it's like the same.
Will be very thanks if someone knows how to fix that problem.

main

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'modules/TestModule.dart';

Future main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
    1337,
  );

  print('Listening on localhost:${server.port}');

  await for (HttpRequest request in server) { 
    switch (request.uri.path) {
      case "/test":
        await testHandler(request);
      break;
      default:
    }
  }
}
```

TestModule

```
import 'dart:io';
Future<void> testHandler(HttpRequest req) async {
  await req.response
  ..write("hello")
  ..close();
}
```

Log

```
Bad state: StreamSink is closed
#0      _StreamSinkImpl.add (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:599:7)
#1      _HttpOutboundMessage.add (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:820:11)
#2      _IOSinkImpl.write (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:734:5)
#3      _HttpOutboundMessage.write (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:828:11)
#4      testHandler (file:///root/dart_prog/modules/TestModule.dart:3:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///root/dart_prog/main.dart:15:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Happens on

```
await req.response
  ..write("hello")
  ..close();
```

when trying to load page.

Comment: Can you add the full exception? I think you cut the first line of the error which should explain the problem.

Comment: It's in title actually but edited so it won't cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem but there are a problem with the following code:

```
  await req.response
  ..write("hello")
  ..close();
```

This will not await the `Future` returned from `close()` but instead try to await `req.response` which is not a `Future`.

So what you want is instead the following:

```
Future<void> testHandler(HttpRequest req) async {
  await (req.response
    ..write("hello"))
    .close();
}
```

But you have another problem which is you assume that `close()` will flush the buffer which is not the case:

> NOTE: Writes to the IOSink may be buffered, and may not be flushed by a call to close(). To flush all buffered writes, call flush() before calling close().

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/IOSink/close.html

So you need to await `flush()`. So the final method should look like this:

```
Future<void> testHandler(HttpRequest req) async {
  final response = req.response;
  response.write("hello");
  await response.flush();
  return response.close();
}
```

Since we returns a `Future` (since out method is `async`) we can just return the `Future` from `close()`.

But since I cannot reproduce your problem I don't know if this will fix your issues. But the code will be more correct with my changes. :)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't fixed my problem.

Comment: Ah, this is my mistake, i found where i'm closing response stream, anyway thanks :)